# Difference instead of sum mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need to calculate difference not sum, is there any way to do this. Here is desired example if sub aggreagate function exists.

```
SELECT p.*,SUB(p.orders) AS diff FROM products AS p GROUP BY p.id HAVING p.orders<0;
```

This is just example, not real table, just for example. The idea is to compare if first value is bigger than next values. Real example is if query returns two rows compare two values (orders count) of this tow rows in one query.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you sample data and expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql get difference instead of SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908943/mysql-get-difference-instead-of-sum)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is only applicable when there are always 2 rows with the same p.id and different orders. If you have more than 2 rows which you would subtract from which?

So in the special case that you always have 2 rows per  p.id then what you need is not a group function but join table products with itself like:

Select p1.id, (p1.orders - p2.orders) as diff
from products p1 inner join products p2 on p1.id = p2.id
where p1.orderid <> p2.orderid

This will only work if you always have 2 different orders per product.