# mysql get difference instead of SUM

Tags: mysql, database, sum, difference

I have the following query :

```
SELECT SUM(P_QTY) 
FROM rankhistory
WHERE P_ID= '1'
AND RH_DATE>=1438556400
AND RH_DATE<1438642800
```

The above query returns `268`

The result set contains two elements of P_QTY which are `160` and `108`

Now what I want is be able to receive the difference instead of the sum, so what I want my query to return is `52`, how can I achieve that through sql query?
Please note that the subquery can return more than one result, and the intended is get the total change. For example if query returns `168` `160` `150`, the result should be `18`.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer this correctly, For example, is it possible to have more than two rows returned based on your where clause? And if more than two are returned, what difference do you want returned?

Comment: Hello @a'r, sorry for not specifying those details, they are now added to the question.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no aggregate function for difference, but since you know exactly which rows to use, you can select each value as its own subquery, then subtract the two columns from one another in a single select statement.

```
SELECT a.op, b.op, a.op - b.op as diff
FROM (SELECT 10 as op) a
JOIN (SELECT 8 as op) b
```

Expressed in accordance with your schema, it would probably look like this:

```
SELECT a.op, b.op, a.op - b.op as diff
FROM (SELECT P_QTY as op FROM rankhistory WHERE P_QTY = 160) a
JOIN (SELECT P_QTY as op FROM rankhistory WHERE P_QTY = 108) b
```

To use this approach regularly in an application, however, you'll want to handle it based on ID's or something else easily selectable and meaningful.

It sounds like you want something else, though. Perhaps you're interested in the difference between max and min during a date range?

```
SELECT MAX(P_QTY) - MIN(P_QTY) as diff
FROM rankhistory
WHERE rh_date BETWEEN '1438556400' AND '1438642800'
```

Comment: I suspect that there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks @Royall Spence, the last answer works like a charm, I really like the Max and Min introduced there, completely nailed it ! that's exactly what I needed !